# Regex for a string followed by another string (separated by any number of spaces) without using capture groups

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to get the 2nd string in a line where there are 2 strings are separated by any number of spaces

e.g.

```
test1                       test2
```

In this case i want a regex to match "test2" without matching any of the spaces and without using capture groups

I've tried

```
(?<=\s).*
```

but this only gets rid of the first space, I also tried

```
(?<=\s+).* or (?<=\s*).*
```

but regex101.com says

> Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to match multiple space in lookbehind. Following regex does the job:

```
(?<=\s)\S+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX4iE5/1)